# Rails get parameter is nil in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get

I have a simple search form:

```
<%= form_with(url: recherche_path, method: "get", class: "side-box", local: true) do %>
    <div id="search-container">
        <%= text_field_tag(:q, nil, placeholder: "Rechercher un mot dans le dictionnaire...", id: "search") %>
        <ul id="search-results"></ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

It redirects to this controller method:

```
def recherche
    @results = Word.search(params['q']).first(20)
end
```

Which uses this model scope:

```
scope :search, ->(content) {
quoted_content = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_string(content)
where("content % :content", content: content).
  order(Arel.sql("similarity(content, '#{quoted_content}') DESC"))
}
```

Everything works fine in development but in production I get the following error:

> no implicit conversion of nil into String

It seems the params[:q] returns nil, but I can't find why?

EDIT

Here is the HTML form rendered (see it in action [here](https://lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/)):

```
<form class="side-box" action="/dictionnaire/recherche" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="get">
        <div id="search-container" data-children-count="1">
            <input type="text" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Rechercher un mot dans le dictionnaire..." class="">
            <ul id="search-results"></ul>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems that could exists a difference between the prod and dev configuration. What about `Rails.configuration.action_controller.per_form_csrf_tokens`, it could be required for production and you aren't sending it on your search request.

Comment: Compare and ensure once that the production code and development codes are same.

Comment: @dev-cc Rails.configuration.action_controller.per_form_csrf_tokens return "true" in production. The codes are exactly the same in production and development.

Comment: Why did you add the `local: true` in the form tag? what does it mean? have you tried without it?

Comment: Yes I tried without it and same issue unfortunately. The local: true allows to redirect to the form action URL when you press "enter".

Comment: Is there any parameter permitting logic on that controller on a before action for the given method?

Comment: I have def word_params params.fetch(:word, {}) end but I don't think it's called for this custom "recherche" method

Comment: Can be something related to your NGINX configuration. Can you also include this one too ?

Comment: @RocKhalil is the NGINX configuration in the "nginx-rc.service" file? (sorry, I'm a noob in server management and paid someone to handle it)

Comment: @nico_lrx it should be somewhere in `/etc/nginx/sites_enabled` or `/etc/nginx/conf.d` ; however, I tried your site and i'm getting data back from the server. I'm not sure why you're seeing null params

Answer (score 0):

First lookin your server log to make sure your params are actually getting passed from the web page. You should see something like the following (only specific to YOUR params, this is just from an app I had running:

```
Started GET "/trips/algeria" for ::1 at 2020-08-31 15:42:35 -0700
Processing by TripsController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"facets"=>"algeria"}
```

Then make sure the params are actually available in the controller. I would remove all unnecessary code to make sure that your assumptions are right about `params['q']` being nil. You don't need to be doing any `Word.search(params['q']).first(20)`. That just increases the surface area to debug. I'd personally just log `params['q']` to my server log to make sure it's there.

If it is in fact sent to the server, and nil in the controller, it's probably a strong parameters issue and needs to be be permitted.

If you find that `params['q']` isn't in fact nil in the controller, the error may be coming from your search code.

Another thing that comes to mind is that "strong params" is somewhat configurable in different versions of Rails. I'm not sure what version you're on, but you might have a config setting like one of the following, that is different in production and development:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes =
config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters =
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems the params are not passed from the web page. Here are the logs:
Started GET "/dictionnaire/recherche"
Processing by WordsController#recherche as HTML
{"controller"=>"words", "action"=>"recherche"}

And "params": 

parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  controller: words
  action: recherche
permitted: true

Comment: @nico_lrx Also I don't see a submit button on your form, and wonder how it's submitting. If you are submitting via ajax manually, you need to explicitly pass the form data. But in that case you might as well use the rails default and not use `local:true`.

Comment: @nico_lrx if this answer helped you solve your problem please accept it and award the bounty.

Comment: unfortunately, I tried to add a submit button, and params are still not passed. I don't submit the form trough Ajax, it's a normal form redirecting to a search page.

Comment: @nico_lrx could you post the form HTML that is rendered?

Comment: I just edited the question to add the form. You can also see it in action here: https://lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/

Comment: Looks like the form is submitting through ajax with `query: ` and `POST`. Also seems to be working now. Moi aussi je suis francophone :)

Comment: this is for the autocompletion, I'm willing to redirect the user to the /recherche page when they hit enter. But in that case it doesn't transmit params.

Comment: I think that would be unexpected behavior anyway, to have auto completion AND go to a different page when they hit enter. Either way, I'm sure that whatever code is detecting `remote: true` also attaches to the `onSubmit` of the form, and doing a `preventDefault` on the form submission so it never sends. This is pretty standard. If you want both to happen you'll probably have to write your own `onSubmit` handler and not use the `remote:true`.

Comment: The thing is it works perfectly well on another app hosted on Heroku (https://dicopedia.com/). Anyway, I will try with my own onSubmit handler ;)